# What is denied when doing "sudo su postgres"

Tags: ubuntu

I have a machine with Ubuntu 14.04.2. It has PostgreSQL installed. My user can `sudo`. If I do `sudo su postgres`, I get the following on the screen and it switches me to the `postgres` user:

`Access denied
Access denied
su: Autentication failure
(Ignored)`

Functionally, it is still working. But I would like to find out what is causing this output and I'm not sure where to look.

If I do `sudo -i -u postgres` it does not give the `Access denied` output.

Comment: You are not providing the password to the postgres user.  [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20239401/how-to-sudo-su-postgres-on-a-remote-server-with-a-script) explains what is going on.

Comment: @Ramhound - I think you misunderstand my question - it *does* switch user, it's not asking me for a password. It get the prompt as the `postgres` user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem, in the end, turned out that there is a `postgres` user already in Active Directory. During the installation, PBIS got installed first thus when the PostgreSQL package got installed, the user was found but as it is not a local user, all sort of problems occurred.